# C++ Python Not Always Executing Python Script

Tags: python, c++, hardware

I currently have a piece of hardware connected to C++ code using the MFC (Windows programming) framework. Basically the hardware is passing in image frames to my C++ code. In my C++ code, I am then calling a Python script using the CPython (Python embedding in C++) API to execute a model on that image. I've been noticing some weird behavior with the images though.

My C++ code is executing my Python script perfectly until some frame in the range of 80-90. After that point, my C++ code, for some reason, just stops executing the Python script. Despite that, the C++ code is still running normally - EXCEPT for the fact (which I just stated) that it's not executing the Python script.

Something to note: my Python script takes 5 seconds to execute the FIRST time, but then only 0.02 seconds to execute each frame after that first frame (I think due to the model getting set up).

At first, I thought it was a problem with the speed, so I replaced all my Python code with just a "time.sleep()" call with varying time, and, even if I sleep 5 seconds each C++ call to Python still always gets executed. As a result, I don't think it's a matter of the total time. For instance, if I do "time.sleep(1)" which sleeps for a second (which is longer than my Python script execution time AFTER the first frame), my Python script still always gets executed.

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening? Could it be because of the uneven running times? Since it's taking 5 seconds to run the first frame and then significantly faster for each frame after that. Could it be that the Python is somehow unable to catch up after that time period?

This is my first time executing C++/Python on hardware, so I'm also new to this. Any helps would be greatly appreciated!

To give some idea of my code, here is a snippet:

```
if (pFuncFrame && PyCallable_Check(pFuncFrame)) {
    PyObject* pArgs = PyTuple_New(1);
    PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 0, PyUnicode_FromString("img.bmp"));
    PyObject_CallObject(pFuncFrame, pArgs);
    std::cout << "Called the frame function";
}
else {
    std::cout << "Did not get the frame function";
}
```

Comment: You've written this pretty well and it's not really your fault but I'm afraid I doubt we'd be able to diagnose this from here :/ You're probably going to have to narrow it down a bit more first (potentially with the assistance of someone who can see your machine, or at least someone in a chatroom you can go through the motions with). Good luck!

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica Thank you for your comment! Hm I realize it's probably hard to debug this without seeing it. Just hoping that others may have experienced something similar.

Comment: What does “just stops executing the Python script” mean?  Are you saying that the “Did not get the frame function” message appears?  Are you checking for errors from all the various functions that can fail (unlike in your snippet!)?

Answer (score 1):

I'm willing to bet that the first execution ends in a Python exception which isn't cleared until you execute some new Python statement in the second iteration, which therefore fails immediately. I recommend fixing the memory leaks and adding some error handling code to get some diagnostics (which will be useful either which way). For example (haven't tried, since you didn't provide a compilable example, but the following shouldn't be too far off):

```
if (pFuncFrame && PyCallable_Check(pFuncFrame)) {
    PyObject* pArgs = PyTuple_New(1);
    PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 0, PyUnicode_FromString("img.bmp"));
    PyObject* res = PyObject_CallObject(pFuncFrame, pArgs);
    if (!res) {
        if (PyErr_Occurred()) PyErr_Print();
        else std::cerr << "Python exception without error set\n";
    } else {
        Py_DECREF(res);
        std::cout << "Called the frame function";
    }
    Py_DECREF(pArgs);
}
else {
    std::cout << "Did not get the frame function";
}
```